# forEach of object with value "0", is returning integer 1

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, object, foreach

I have a window/property object, which I'm looping through with a forEach - `window.gaData["UA-MY-ID-NUMBER"].experiments` And contains two key values.

And the data which sits in the object:

```
{KGtpiL5KTAee3Dj6w7GRaA: "1", FPX0F0xuTaOzWE7b14odbg: "0"}
```

You can see, one value is clearly "0".

**I want to loop through this object and only display the key value, IF the value is 0.**
HOWEVER, when I `forEach` loop through my object, for some reason, my "0" is coverted to `1` and I can't figure out why.

**Here's how I'm looping through my object:**

```
Object.keys(window.gaData["UA-MY-ID-NUMBER"].experiments).forEach(function(key, value){
      if (window.gaData["UA-MY-ID-NUMBER"].experiments[key] === "0") {
      console.log('key, value: ', key, value);

      result += `
        <div>
          <p value="${key}">${key}:Experiement: ${key} is set to variant: ${value}</p>
          <button id="${key}">Switch variant</button>
        </div>
        `
      document.getElementById('variant-0-container').innerHTML = result;
    }
  });
```

**And here's what console.logs into my browser:**

```
key, value:  FPX0F0xuTaOzWE7b14odbg 1
window.gaData["UA-MY-ID-NUMBER"].experiments
{KGtpiL5KTAee3Dj6w7GRaA: "1", FPX0F0xuTaOzWE7b14odbg: "0"}
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Any pointers?

I've also tried changing my condition in the if statement, to `=== 0`, `== "0"` and even `== 0`, which gives me the same output.

Comment: You are not showing how `value` is declared/defined.  Part of your code is missing.

Comment: @Greedo actually updated it correctly, apologies all for not adding my coding correctly.  Accidently missed that out.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in `Array.prototype.forEach()` the second argument is the `index` of the loop, not the value of the object your are looping.
More about in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
window.gaData = {"UA-MY-ID-NUMBER": {}};

window.gaData["UA-MY-ID-NUMBER"].experiments = {KGtpiL5KTAee3Dj6w7GRaA: "1", FPX0F0xuTaOzWE7b14odbg: "0"};


Object.keys(window.gaData["UA-MY-ID-NUMBER"].experiments).forEach(function(key){
      var value = window.gaData["UA-MY-ID-NUMBER"].experiments[key]
      if (value === "0") {
      console.log('key, value: ', key, value);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please don't make assumption about the OP's code. Let them update their question.

Comment: Thank you so much @greedo! I knew the answer was a simple/obvious, but thank you. I'll have a good read to understand this issue further!  Thanks again - this worked!

Comment: @FelixKling I knew was not the best, but when i tried to analyse the code was the only plausible reason